# KMP algorithm pattern calculation issue

Tags: python, algorithm

Here is my code and test case. My question is, it seems the value of KMP pattern will never increase, since in last iteration, we checked `pattern[i] != pattern[j]`, and in current round `if (j == -1) or (pattern[j] == pattern[i])` cannot be true unless `j == -1`?

```
def findPattern(pattern):

   j = -1
   next = [-1] * len(pattern)
   i = 0 # next[0] is always -1, by KMP definition

   while (i+1 < len(pattern)):
       if (j == -1) or (pattern[j] == pattern[i]):
           i += 1
           j += 1
           if pattern[i] != pattern[j]:
               next[i] = j
           else:
               next[i] = next[j]
       else:
           j = next[j]

   return next

if __name__ == "__main__":

   # print findPattern("aaaab")
   print findPattern("abaabc")
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: I am getting correct output when using KMP with your `findPattern(pattern)` function, could you post what you expect? Also, it seems that https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109281/kmp-string-match-algorithm-in-python and https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/107909/knuth-morris-pratt-string-match-algorithm verified that you are getting indeed the correct output and improved your code.

Comment: @jermenkoo, thanks for the comments. I checked again and you are correct. I just want to confirm, when condition of "pattern[i] != pattern[j]" is triggered in last loop iteration, in the next loop iteration, condition "pattern[j] == pattern[i]" could never be true and its related next pattern value will always decrease since j=next[j] is trigger, correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already increased i and j, so you are actually checking `pattern[i+1] != pattern[j+1]` after `if (j == -1) or (pattern[j] == pattern[i])`

Comment: Thanks discover, I just want to confirm my understanding is correct, when condition of "pattern[i] != pattern[j]" is triggered in last loop iteration, in the next loop iteration, condition "pattern[j] == pattern[i]" could never be true and its related next pattern value will always decrease since j=next[j] is trigger, correct? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa And your code is wrong.  findPattern("abaabc") should return [-1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1].

Comment: Thanks discover for confirming my understanding is correct.

Comment: Hi discover, for "abaabc", I am a bit lost. I tested my code will output [-1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 2], the 2nd element is zero, which means if prefix ab does not match, we should compare the position of element b, to a to see if there is a possible match. I think it is correct? Your return is -1, which means if ab prefix does not match at position b, we do not need to compare the position of b to a again, wondering why? If you could elaborate a bit more, it will be great. :)

Comment: I think your understanding of kmp is different from mine. My return is -1, which means that if 'ab' prefix matches in current positions (not means that 'ab' does not match) but the character in the next positons do not match,  then we move the current postion of pattern string to -1 (yes,  we know the character in current position is 'b',  does not match the 'a' in postion 0) and try to match the next charater in next step, which means we should try match the 'a' in position 0 of pattern string.

Comment: Thanks discover for the clarification, is there any functional issue in my KMP code? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Lin Ma. You can test your code by solving the problem: http://poj.org/problem?id=3461

Comment: Sure discover, will do, but what do you think wrong with my code specifically (any anti-logical)? Thanks.